# Is Jonathan Oliver's EventStore actively developed?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, neventstore

I'm starting a new project that will be hosted on Windows Azure. 
I'm using RavenDb as the backend and I would like to use CQRS and event sourcing.

I read good reviews of Jonathan's EventStore and it would fit perfectly into my architecture, as it is a thin layer and can use RavenDb as a store.
Now, I've noticed that the 3.0 release (latest official) is a year old and the new 3.1 hasn't been released yet (there is some activity in the branch).
I would like to go for the 3.1 version as it has CommonDomain project integrated, but I don't have any issues with referencing version 3.0 and current CommonDomain separatelly.

I am just wondering if the EventStore is actively developed and will be maintained, especially since Greg Young released his EventStore (geteventstore.com).
I am a bit reluctant to go for it, as it comes with it's own persistance and AFAIK I wouldn't be able to store my events in my RavenDb.

So to sum it up:

1. Is Jonathan's EventStore live?
2. If yes, should I go for the current official 3.0 release and reference CommonDomain project separatelly?
3. Is 3.1 branch (with CommonDomain merged) ready?
4. Should I switch to Greg Young's EventStore after all?
5. Or maybe should I investigate Lokad.CQRS? (I don't think it uses Jonathan's EventStore)

PS. I don't mind forking joliver's EventStore and contribute fixes / minor features.

Comment: Why don't you contact the current developer, if there is one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using Joliver's EventStore in three systems currently in production and I intend to use it for more projects that will see production soon.

I think one of the reasons that there is less activity in the project compared to other projects out there is that it is very stable as it is. As far as I am concerned the code base is one of the best I have seen in terms of architecture and quality. Most of the activity now is plugins for different types of persistence.

The only thing I needed that wasn't in it when I got started was the possibility to upconvert events so I added that.

And to answer some of your questions.

1. I think it's live enough. I wont let it die anyway.
2. Go with the current release and the separate CommonDomain to allow for Nuget management of references.
3. No, I don't think it is.

Comment: Thanks for boosting my confidence in EventStore ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's actively developed. There are several people helping me move toward the upcoming 3.1 release.

Comment: @JonathanOliver - thank you, Jonathan. Could you please comment on the ETA of 3.1 and whether I can start using this branch right now?

Comment: We'll be releasing 3.1 this month & we'll get working on the next version for release by the end of the year. We plan on providing a replacement for CommonDomain that will be less focused on DDD, so that you can use event sourcing for areas of your system that aren't using DDD as well as for sagas. I will also be rewriting the Raven implementation to make it more performant for replay by date as well as for aggregates / event streams with millions of events.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. Where is the best place to ask questions about EventStore? Do you have a mailing list? - I think I will start with forking repo on Github.

Comment: Right now, Stack Overflow is by far the best place.